# How to transfer Ethereum from one wallet to another wallet by using web3?

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js, vanity

I am in the process of developing a custom ETH wallet, I am able to generate the public/private keys by using vanity eth. After receiving the amount in this wallet, I need to send ETH to another wallet for which I am trying to use web3. How do I do this? The wallet currently have few ETH in it but when I try to check the balance with web3 code it shows zero balance. So how do I transfer ETH from one wallet to another using web3 code, please advice.

My code for get balance of my wallet address is as below.

```
<script src="./node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Web3 = require('web3');
    var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
    console.log("Balance = " + web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance('Wallet_address'), 'ether').toNumber());
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: acct1, to:acct2, value: web3.toWei(1, 'ether'), gasLimit: 21000, gasPrice: 20000000000})
```

This is how I performed an ether transaction in a previous project. 
Also in the future posting here, for the time being, may get you a quicker response https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I already did this but it's working in web3 generated ether address not working into vanity generated ether address. My wallet address have 6 ether balance,But when i checked that using web3 code which is given below, It shows me balance 0.If it gives balance 0 then how can web3 will send ether to other wallet?

Here is my code to get balance of ether wallet.
web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance('Wallet_address'), 'ether').toNumber()

Comment: Are you positive Vanity is actually populating/creating the addresses correctly?  Im looking more into it currently but want to clarify

Comment: Yes, vanity-eth is generating address pair currectly.

Comment: How are you adding in the initial ether to the account?

Comment: Using coinpayment

Comment: and still looking into it, so does coinpayment work for web3 generated wallets?

Comment: @DharaChauhan did created user ether wallet address?? and u made any transactions & exchange??